# Why no slash coming in location of file , i tried reinstalling git , node , react but problem does not go

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, bash

npm start

> client@0.1.0 start
> react-scripts start

/usr/bin/bash: C:UsersRamanAppDataLocalTempstart-1656145085083.sh: command not found

Comment: what is your `node` version? (`node --version`)

Comment: Node version v16.13.0
i also tried running on smaller version but same error

Comment: You should give more information regarding your environment because it seems you are on windows, but you are trying to run a bash script. Bash scripts are usually meant for linux environments. To help us help you, please state where you are running `npm run start`: in CMD, powershell, cygwin, etc? Also include the version of node How did you install CRA (create react app)? Include the exact output you get when you run `npm run start`. Also include the exact output you get when you run `node --version`. ALL of these things should be included in your question

Comment: If you are unable to get all of this information, you can try any of the existing online IDEs. I recommend stackblitz. There is also https://vscode.dev/ which is just vscode running in your browser. If you already have project files, you can probably use that. The only caveat is that there is no access to command line to install stuff, but you can install extensions

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because the node script uses a path with `\` instead of `\\` or '`/`'

Check your react script for that of path parameter.

An alternative is to:

- use VSCode and its [`microsoft/vscode-npm-scripts`](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-npm-scripts) extension
- or use a [full-fledged Linux environment with WSL2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install)

Comment: Of interest: https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/2638#issuecomment-872521336=

Comment: it is running fine for all other things but it dont run or even install new react project

Comment: where should i check for the slashes

Comment: @RamanKumar What version of OS, Git and npm/node are you using?

Comment: @RamanKumar Check the script specified by the `package.json` that your `npm start` uses.

Comment: Node version v16.13.0
git version 2.36.1.windows.1

Comment: even the command for creating new react project is not running ( npx create-react-app raman) so no chance of checking package.json

Comment: same error while creating new project

Comment: @RamanKumar For testing, I would try the same through VSCode and its npm extension: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-npm-scripts. At least, it [does escape the backslash](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-npm-scripts/blob/be117cba5dd3d050054d2aff7a35b477a1b085be/src/main.ts#L805-L815=)

Comment: please help i have interview in 2 days and i need to prepare for that and react is not even running

Comment: @RamanKumar Just in case: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/10132#issuecomment-734114764=. But would a Linux environment like WSL2 (on your Windows machine) work better for you (rather than using Git bash)